# Parse Tree Of Structs Easily With getline()?

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, struct

This is a watered down version of a program that I'm working on. In this example, I'd like to parse through a text file and create a tree of Branch structs.

```
struct Branch {
    int value = -1;
    Branch *positive;
    Branch *negative;
}
```

This is an example of what the text file would look like...

```
First Tree>
    Value:      5
    Positive:
        Value:      7
        Positive:   X
        Negative:
            Value:      23
            Positive:   X
            Negative:   X
    Negative:   X
Another Tree>
    Value:      1
    Positive:
        Value:      2
        Positive:   X
        Negative:   X
    Negative:
        Value:      3
        Positive:   X
        Negative:   X
Third Tree>
    Value:      19
    Positive:   X
    Negative:   X
```

The names, which come before the `>`, should be ignored. There will *always* be 3 trees in the correct order, and I have pointers to them.

```
Branch *firsttree;
Branch *anothertree;
Branch *thirdtree;
```

I'd imagine creating an array of pointers to the 3 Branch pointers (firsttree, anothertree, thirdtree), then iterating through them would be easiest way to ensure that we can put this into a loop.

I'd like to use `getline()` for this and not rely on some parsing library.

This is some psuedocode of what I'd expect the data to look like after being read:

```
//firsttree
{
    value: 5,
    positive: {
        value: 7,
        positive: nullptr,
        negative: {
            value: 23,
            positive: nullptr,
            negative: nullptr
        }
    },
    negative: nullptr
}

//anothertree
{
    value: 1,
    positive: {
        value: 2,
        positive: nullptr,
        negative: nulptr
    },
    negative: {
        value: 3,
        positive: nullptr,
        negative: nulptr
    }
}

//thirdtree
{
    value: 19,
    positive: nullptr,
    negative: nulptr
}
```

Here it is in an image format:
[image]

Is there a way to easily loop through the input file relying on `std::getline()`? If so, could you help give me some psuedocode for achieving it, since I'm mostly getting lost on keeping track on the index and hopping into children nodes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't close the question while I am making an answer - it is a waste of two hours of my life to make an answer and then the question is already closed.  (it seems to happen to me a lot...)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, I don't think that I did that. :0

Comment: Not you - the people that voted to close the question

Comment: @JerryJeremiah happens to me a lot, too. Consider posting a feature request on [meta] asking/prompting users to not close a question while an answer is in progress of being typed up for it.

Answer (score 0):

With this example, I have opted for code that is easy to understand rather than code that is robust and fault tolerant.  What that means is that this code relies on the input file having EXACTLY the info in your specification and there is no code that checks the input file is valid - or even that it exists.  The reason for that is I think the code is easier to understand without all that input validity checking - but of course you can't use the code without adding all that stuff.

This program reads the file from input.txt in your format, stores it in memory using your structure, and then prints the data it read in the output you specified.  Let me know if you need more info on how the code works and I will add more details.

The Branch structure is recursive by design because the structure contains pointers to structure of its own type.  So the secret to input and output of a structure like Branch is to do everything recursively.

For example, when a branch is to be parsed:

- first read the value
- then recursively read another branch for the positive side (using the same parsing code so that it can handle reading even more branches)
- then recursively read another branch for the negative side (using the same parsing code so that it can handle reading even more branches)

So both the reading and printing parts are recursive:

You can try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkWv_G9mI

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct Branch {
    int value;
    Branch *positive;
    Branch *negative;
};

Branch *firsttree   = NULL;
Branch *anothertree = NULL;
Branch *thirdtree   = NULL;

void printbranch(Branch *branch, std::string indent)
{
    std::cout << "{\n";
    std::cout << indent << "    value: " << branch->value << ",\n";

    std::cout << indent << "    positive: ";
    if (branch->positive)
        printbranch(branch->positive, indent + "    ");
    else
        std::cout << "nullptr,\n";

    std::cout << indent << "    negative: ";
    if (branch->negative)
        printbranch(branch->negative, indent + "    ");
    else
        std::cout << "nullptr\n";

    std::cout << indent << "}\n";
}

void printtree(std::string treename, Branch *branch)
{
    std::cout << "//" << treename << "\n";
    printbranch(branch, "");
    std::cout << std::endl; // now we want to flush the output
}

Branch* readbranch(std::ifstream &file)
{
    Branch *branch = new Branch;
    std::string line, token, value;
    for (int currentitem = 0; currentitem < 3; currentitem++)
    {
        std::getline(file, line);
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        ss >> token;

        if (token == "Value:")
            ss >> branch->value;
        else if (token == "Positive:")
            branch->positive = !(ss >> value)?readbranch(file):nullptr;
        else if (token == "Negative:")
            branch->negative = !(ss >> value)?readbranch(file):nullptr;
    }
    return branch;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");

    // read the firsttree
    std::getline(file, line); // read the line with the >
    firsttree = readbranch(file);

    // read anothertree
    std::getline(file, line); // read the line with the >
    anothertree = readbranch(file);

    // read the thirdtree
    std::getline(file, line); // read the line with the >
    thirdtree = readbranch(file);

    // print the trees
    printtree("firsttree",firsttree);
    printtree("anothertree",anothertree);
    printtree("thirdtree",thirdtree);

    return 0;
}
```